# Adding count number above a bar

Tags: r

I would like to create a bar graph that adds a number, indicating the exact count above, or adjacent to  the "yes", "no" columns, for the following data set

```
library(ISLR)
df <- College
table(df$Private)
barplot(table(df$Private))
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Private))+
  geom_bar()+
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1)
```